# MySQL Workbench: how can I change the font of the resultset grid headers (column names)?

Tags: mysql-workbench

From Preferences -> Fonts I can increase the font size of the Resultset Grid, but this doesn't affect the font of the column names.

I am using V 6.3 on macOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. The standard system font is used there.